# Using WP_Query To Get Posts Randomly From today

Tags: wp-query, date-time

In the logic of the data_query(); I found this WP_Query sample:

```
<!-- Second Senses Featured -->
    <ul id="featuredSecond" class="featured-second">

      <?php
      $today = getdate();
      $args = array(
        'tag_slug__in' => array( 'destacado'),
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'post_type' => 'any',
        'offset' => 3,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'date_query' => array(
          array(
            'after' => 'Today',
            'inclusive' => true,

            )
          ),
        'post_status' => array(
          'publish'
          )
        );

      $featured = new WP_Query($args);

      if ( $featured->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $featured->have_posts() ) : $featured->the_post();
      ?>

      <li id="<?php the_slug(); ?>-<?php the_id(); ?>">
        <article id="post-<?php the_id(); ?>" class="cf"  role="article">

          <?php featured_content('thumb-480x300'); ?>

          <div class="featured-box">
            <h1 class="featured-title cf">
              <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
              </a>
            </h1>
          </div>
          <!--featured-box-->

        </article>

      </li>
      <?php
      endwhile;
      endif;
      wp_reset_postdata();
      ?>
```

But everything is rotating with post with 3 week old.. or more!

how this logic is not working?

if you notice there is a variable called $today , but I didn't make it work...

thanks

Comment: if you inspect the output of `var_dump($featured)` after you run the query, you'll get a better idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: The `$today` variable is set but never used

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a parameter value `Today` as you used in `date_query`.

If you want to return today's post then you should provide date value to `date_query` as you stored current date in `$today` array. So here is your query now.

```
      $today = getdate();
      $args = array(
        'tag_slug__in' => array( 'destacado'),
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'post_type' => 'any',
        'offset' => 3,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
              'year'  => $today['year'],
              'month' => $today['mon'],
              'day'   => $today['mday'],
            ),
          ),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        );

        $featured = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: documentation for `after` says "accepts strtotime()-compatible string", which I believe can parse strings like "today", "tomorrow" "week from thursday", etc..

Comment: @Milo didn't know that. I will have to try it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use $today instead of 'Today', like so:

```
$today = getdate();
$args = array(
    'tag_slug__in' => array( 'destacado'),
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post_type' => 'any',
    'offset' => 3,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'date_query' => array(
      array(
        'after' => $today,
        'inclusive' => true,
        )
      ),
    'post_status' => array(
      'publish'
      )
    );
  $featured = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try replacing `getdate()` with `current_time('Y-m-d')`

Comment: Please explain _why_ this answer is helpful.